# If given matrix $A$ and $AX$, find $X$.

Tags: matrices

Given matrices:

$$A= \begin{pmatrix}2&0&1\\1&-1&0\\0&3&-2\end{pmatrix}$$

$$A\,X =\begin{pmatrix}3&-1\\2&5\\0&4\end{pmatrix}$$
Find $X$

My method was a very slow method as I had to solve two systems of equations with 3 variables each. Does anyone have any ideas of a better method to do this? I am thinking something with inverse matrices.

Comment: Supposed $AX$ means $A·X$,  you have $A^{-1}·AX=X$

Comment: Oh yes, I see now, so just left multiply $AX$ by $A^{-1}$Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

$$A^{-1}(AX) = (A^{-1}A)X = X$$
Using any method to calculate the inverse matrix:

$$A^{-1} = 
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{2}{7} & \frac{3}{7} & \frac{1}{7} \\
    \frac{2}{7} & \frac{-4}{7} & \frac{1}{7} \\
    \frac{3}{7} & \frac{-6}{7} & \frac{-2}{7} \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

We get 
$$X=A^{-1}(AX) = \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{2}{7} & \frac{3}{7} & \frac{1}{7} \\
    \frac{2}{7} & \frac{-4}{7} & \frac{1}{7} \\
    \frac{3}{7} & \frac{-6}{7} & \frac{-2}{7} \\
    \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}
    3 & -1 \\
    2 & 5 \\
    0 & 4 \\
    \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{12}{7} & \frac{17}{7}\\
    \frac{-2}{7} & \frac{-18}{7}\\
    \frac{-3}{7} & \frac{-41}{7}\\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is invertible, then you can left-multiply by $A^{-1}$ to recover $X$. Note that you don’t have to invert $A$ explicitly. Since the RREF of any invertible square matrix is the identity, row-reducing it is equivalent to multiplying it by its inverse. So, if you row-reduce the augmented matrix $[A\mid AX]$ you’ll end up with $[I\mid A^{-1}AX]=[I\mid X]$ when you’re done.